# jQuery draggable limit specific Table tds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I know it's only possible to limit the area of an element within a certain "parent" element but is there a workaround in any way to block some specific cells in a `table td` to prevent a user to drag through it?
This seems a little bit strange but I want to creat some kind of board where players can drag "units" and "enemies" but should not be able to drag their units through enemies.
Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/YRfVd/72/
you can place a green and blue div inside the table these should represent enemies, red divs represent player units. Players are able to drag a red div over another to switch the position of both and I'd like to have a workaround to prevent the player to move through green and blue divs.
Does anyone knows a way?
I would be sooooo happy if someone could lend me his/her knowledge

Comment: There is a discussion here about cancelling drag mid flight, but its the closest I can find to a solution - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-cancel-drag-while-dragging

Comment: Do you want to prevent dragging through it or prevent an item from being dropped upon it, like reverting it if dropped to the wrong cell. I suspect the latter is much easier to address than confining the drag around to avoid specific cells. Both can be done though.

Comment: I wanted to prevent the user dragging through it and it was quite easy. on `start`event I just check the `top, left, button, right`coordinates of all unaccepted fields in an array. While `drag`I check if the `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` coordinates from the mouse are between those values (so the mouse is over one of those forbidden cells) if thats the case, I freeze to position of the draggable to those coordinates until the mouse moves over it again. this is an older version with view bugs http://jsfiddle.net/YRfVd/75/ I'm currently using more js files so I cant upload the fixed version